# javascript url undefined redirect

Tags: javascript, html

I have some javascript to direct the page to a new url but I get directed to a www.myurl.com/undefined instead.

This is what I have, not sure what is wrong. I have tried also window.location

```
if (r == true) {
    window.location.href = ('http://www.myurl.com/pubs_delete.php?=id'.a_href)
};
```

Thank you for any pointers

Comment: You don't need the parens around the URL

Comment: And JavaScript use `+` for concatenation, not `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
      var a_href;
        if (r == true) {
            window.location.href = ('http://www.myurl.com/pubs_delete.php?=id'+a_href)
        };
```

javascript concatenation  using +(**plus**) sympol ,you are using .(**dot**) sympol that is the problem for u

Answer (score 1):

```
if (r == true) {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.myurl.com/pubs_delete.php?id=' + a_href
};
```

Comment: `?=id` should be `?id=...` instead

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a_href` is a defined variable

```
...delete.php?id=' + a_href
```

string concatenation in javascript is `+`, not `.` and the equal is misplaced

Answer (score 1):

Combining both answers:

```
if (r) {   // r == true is quite redundat
    window.location.href = "http://www.myurl.com/pubs_delete.php?id=" + a_href;
};
```